# SharePoint 2010 Relationships between lists - difference with referencing custom list column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

Just curious, if I try to create a look up (relationship) from source list that is based on a custom list template, I can't access columns that users have defined on the list level (within the list). however, this doesn't seem to be the case with any other content type selection that was made to create the list from. for example, if they selected contacts content type, and define a new column on the list level, it will.....

just a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you cannot make a LookUp Field for a custom column you created?
I do not understand the question completely..
But can give an idea.
If you are able to solve your problem from sharepoint itself or somehow, you can get the schema.xml file of the list where you solved the problem by this.

```
[WebApplicationUrl]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={ListInstanceGuid}
```

to get the list guid of the list that you solved the problem.
go to the list settings of that list. And in the address bar you can see the list GUID.

add the web application url , then paste this line in the address bar, it will prompt to save an xml file. Save the file, open it, There you go, the schema.xml file of that list.